# Why do BigQuery audit logs that use the V2 format, have column names with "_v1_"?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I switched on audit logs via the console using the new V2 format and created a sink to export them to back to BigQuery for analysis:

[image]

The tables that are exported to BigQuery all have "*v1*" in the column names, even though I selected V2 format:

[image]

Then, when I try to query the table, because the column names exceed 128 chars, it throws an error:

[image]

Why are the audit logs being exported using the v1 naming schema, and how do I get around the column names being over the 128 character limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I get around the column names being over the 128 character limit?

I believe the problem is not in referencing long named column path but rather in output column's name
So, to resolve the issue within Legacy SQL - you should provide alias that is compliant with name cnvention.
Or just use Standard SQL - in this case the alias is by default the name of the leaf field (in this case `totalBilledBytes`)

```sql
#legacySQL  
SELECT  
  protopayload_google_cloud_audit_auditlog.
    servicedata_google_cloud_bigquery_logging_v1_auditdata.
    jobCompletedEvent.
    job.
    jobStatistics.
    totalBilledBytes AS totalBilledBytes   
FROM [yourTable]
```

or

```sql
#standardSQL   
SELECT  
  protopayload_google_cloud_audit_auditlog.
    servicedata_google_cloud_bigquery_logging_v1_auditdata.
    jobCompletedEvent.
    job.
    jobStatistics.
    totalBilledBytes    
FROM `yourTable`
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why are the audit logs being exported using the v1 naming schema?

The export being in v2 format refers to the [LogEntry](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry) containing the audit log payload.

The 'v1' in the column name is the version of the BigQuery AuditData  message (specifically a `google.cloud.bigquery.logging.v1.AuditData` protocol buffer), which is stored within in the log entry's proto payload  field. The [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/audit/bigquery/rest/Shared.Types/AuditData), described it in REST style, doesn't expose the version.